# PHP MongoDB Connect to another IP

Tags: php, mongodb, database-connection

I am trying to figure out why I can not connect to `MongoClient()` hosted on some different `IP`. I am using below code to connect to another `IP` and accessing its `DB` and `Collections`

```
<?php

$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$conn = new MongoClient("mongodb://SYSTEMIP:27017", array("username" => $username, "password" => $password));
$database = $conn->testdb; //Creating New Database
$collection = $database->users; //Calling users collection

?>
```

The exception printed is `MongoConnectionException: Failed to connect to: SYSTEM:27017: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.`.

Is there anything that I need to change on system. `MongoDB` is properly installed on the IP that I need to connect to. Pls correct me if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB 2.6 ships with bindIp config set. Look into your config for it.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp

Also, check whether 27017 is TCP permissible. Check for Firewalls or other restrictions.

Comment: When I change bindIp to `0.0.0.0` from `127.0.0.1`, a `32 bit` can connect to my `64 bit` machine, but vice-versa is not working.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.. but I guess if you want to connect to mongodb from various sources you gotta put them up comma seperated there!